# LINQ - Deserialize JSON column and filter

Tags: c#, .net, json, linq, serialization

How to deserialize/serialize a property with JSON string array value and then filter (using where clause) in LINQ inside a lambda expression?

```
void Main()
{
    var regionList = new List<Row>() {
        new Row { RegionJsonList = "[\"QLD\",\"NSW\"]" },
        new Row { RegionJsonList = "[\"TAZ\",\"SA\"]" },
        new Row { RegionJsonList = "[\"QLD\",\"VIC\"]" }
    };

    var filterRegionList = new List<string>() {
        "QLD", "NSW"
    };

    var queryable = regionList.AsQueryable();


    // this is obviously wrong, i just want to find the Row that contains one on filterRegionList
    var result = queryable.Where(r => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(r.RegionJsonList).Contains(filterRegionList));

    result.Count().Dump(); // should be 2

}

class Row
{
    public string RegionJsonList { get;set; }
}
```

Comment: anyone guys? need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following would work:

```
var result =
filterRegionList.Aggregate(regionList,(current,filter) => 
current.Where( r => r.RegionJsonList.Contains(filter)).ToList())
```

Aggregating the `filterRegionList` and `regionList` and thus applying filters for the final result. I did not find a requirement to Deserialize the RegionJsonList, since this would work as is, but you may add that part in  case you are keen.

Also we are applying `And` filter via aggregation, it checks for the rows which contains both the filters, and thus provide the result, you may modify filter to achieve more number of rows, like following will select two entries from original `regionList`

```
var filterRegionList = new List<string>() { "QLD"  };
```

Answer (score 1):

To filter for rows that contain at least one of the entries from `filterRegionList`, you can use [`Enumerable.Intersect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx) and check for non-empty intersections:

```
var resultAny = queryable.Where(r => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(r.RegionJsonList).Intersect(filterRegionList).Any());
```

To filter for rows that contain *all* of the entries from `filterRegionList`, you can use [`Enumerable.Except`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) to remove the row's entries from the filter list.  If everything gets removed, it's a match:

```
var resultAll = queryable.Where(r => !filterRegionList.Except(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(r.RegionJsonList)).Any());
```

(It wasn't entirely clear from your question which you wanted.)